# Opencv boost update gives unhandled exception

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using CvBoost from OpenCV and as long as I leave out the update parameter, everything is fine and the classifier gets trained properly. However, once I try to add more weak learners to the classifier by providing new data and also setting update to true, I get an unhandled exception. Could you please help? Below is part of my code:

```
CvBoostParams params = CvBoostParams(CvBoost::DISCRETE, 1, 0.9, 1, false, NULL);


CvMat* data_f = cvCreateMat(nRows, nCols, CV_32FC1);

CvMat* resp_f = cvCreateMat(nRows, 1, CV_32FC1);

readFeatureFile(fileName, data_f, resp_f);

CvBoost boost = CvBoost();

boost.train(data_f, CV_ROW_SAMPLE, resp_f, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, params);

params.weak_count += 1;

boost.train(data_f, CV_ROW_SAMPLE, resp_f, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, params, true);
```

The exception is in the last line.

Comment: Ok, so this is one of those "guess-the-exception" riddles? Wrong site, but my entry would be "Bad argument (2-th value of 10-th (categorical) variable is not an integer)". Did I win something?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail. Which variable exactly do you mean?

Comment: @userXXXXXX I think you have the idea about this site upside-down: this site is where you post the question. But, you could start with the variables that are used (right after you show the exception). See http://www.sscce.org/}, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762), and [Solve your problem by almost asking a question on StackOverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)

Comment: For starters; stop using the c part of opencv. Switch to the C++ implementation of OpenCV as it's much easier to read & maintain. The only reason to use the old opencv stuff is if you are writing embedded stuff that doesn't support c++.